# Writing ndjson to S3 Bucket using Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to upload `ndjson` data to S3 bucket. But I am struggling to pass that to `S3.putObject()`

#### Following is my JSON Data:

```js
const responseData = uploadData.data.map((upData) => ({
 date: upData.date,
 time: upData.time,
 url: upData.url,
 test1: test1.id,
 test2: test2,
}));
```

#### I am converting the above `JSON` to `ndjson`:

```js
const transformStream = ndjson.stringify();
const outputStream = transformStream.pipe(
 fileSystem.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/data.ndjson')
);
responseData.forEach(function iterator(record) {
 transformStream.write(record);
});
transformStream.end();
```

Now, how do I upload that data into my S3 bucket, please assist, Thanks

Comment: You have to use AWS SDK to do so, you can find examples [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a neat solution without the need of `ndjson` library

Below code will transform your `JSON` data into `ndjson` format (if the data is of following type):

```
[
  {
    "f1": "somedata",
    "f2": "somedata",
    "f3": "somedata"
  },
  {
    "f1": "somedata",
    "f2": "somedata",
    "f3": "somedata"
  }
]

const transformData = (jsonData) => {
 let res = ''
 for (let i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
   res += `${JSON.stringify(jsonData[i])}\n`
 }
 return res
}
```

Then you can simply call `AWS.S3` - `PutObject` Function to put the `ndjson` data into `S3` (following):

```
const result = transformData(Data)

const params = {
  Bucket: bucketName,
  Key: keyName,
  Body: result
}

s3.putObject(params, function () {})
// If you need to get the version ID of the Object (only if versioning is Enabled)
// const verID = (await s3.putObject(params, function () {}).promise()).VersionId
```